# Closing socket exceptions

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

My Windows client is built on the wxWidgets framework, and the client calls the interface of DLL A in the main thread. When performing the following test, there is an issue where the socket cannot be closed:

1. The main thread of the client responds to a button event and calls the interface of DLL A in an asynchronous queue in the client. Inside the interface, it creates thread 1 and listens on port 8888. By using the command "netstat -ano|grep 8888", it can be confirmed that the port is successfully being listened to.
2. The main thread of the client sleeps for 5000 milliseconds. This is only to increase the probability of reproducing the issue. When the main thread of the client is blocked, this problem is more likely to occur.
3. The main thread of the client calls the interface of DLL A, which then calls closesocket() to close the socket listening on port 8888. Normally, after calling closesocket(), thread 1 should release the resources of port 8888. However, there is a chance that after calling closesocket(), the return value of closesocket() is 0, but when checking "netstat -ano|grep 8888", it is found that port 8888 is not released.

There are two points that I don't understand:

1. Why does port 8888 not get released after calling closesocket?This will cause my while loop to never exit, as accept will keep blocking.
2. Why does the probability of encountering the issue increase when the main thread of the client is blocked by a sleep operation? What is the connection between the main thread of the client and the socket establishment and release in the DLL?

I hope someone knowledgeable can provide some guidance. Thank you very much.

demo:

```
void APP::main()
{
    onButton();
}

void APP::onButton(wxCommandEvent & evt)
{
    // Sleep(5000); If the blocking operation is performed here (or elsewhere in the main thread), the subsequent closing of the socket will not be closed
    if (evt.GetId() == open)
    {
        _tasks->async([this]()
        {
            openSocket();
        });
    }
    else if(evt.GetId() == close)
    {
        _tasks->async([this]()
        {
            closeSocket();
        });
    }

}

void DLL::closeSocket()
{
    closeSocket(serverSocket);
}

void DLL::openSocket()
{
    thread t1(myFunction);
    t1.detach();
}

void myFunction()
{
    //Only the abbreviated steps are listed
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(8888);
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, 

    sizeof(serverAddress));
        listen(serverSocket, 5);
        while(true)
        {
            int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientAddressSize);
            if (clientSocket == -1) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to accept client connection." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            // Pass the socket that establishes the connection to the external use
            new transportThread(endpoint, clientSocket);
        }

}
```

I have tried setting SO_LINGER(1,0), SO_LINGER(0,0), and SO_REUSEPORT, but the issue still persists.

Comment: In the `myFunction()` code you have shown, if `accept()` is successful, you are leaking `clientSocket`, which is *also* bound to port 8888. Since "Only the abbreviated steps are listed", are you actually closing `clientSocket` before exiting from `myFunction()`? Please provide a better [mcve].

Comment: `SO_REUSEPORT` is for UDP. Use `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your response. I have made modifications to the demo. In fact, there is an issue with calling closesocket to close the port listening when accept is continuously blocking without any incoming connections.@Remy Lebeau

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your response. I have also used SO_REUSEADDR, but there are still issues. The main problem now is that calling closesocket does not close the port listening.  @user207421